# Cannot get check_uptime plugin for Nagios to work. Unknown status?

Tags: nagios

Hoping you guys might be able to spot what i'm missing here. I'm not able to get a simple check_uptime plugin to work in Nagios.

When I invoke help for the plugin using:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_uptime -h
```

the result is:

```
 usage: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_uptime [-c OPTION]

This script checks uptime and optionally verifies if the uptime
is below MINIMUM or above MAXIMUM uptime treshholds

OPTIONS:
-h Help
-c CRITICAL MIN uptime (minutes)
-w WARNING MIN uptime (minutes)
-C CRITICAL MAX uptime (minutes)
-W WARNING MAX uptime (minutes)
-V Version
```

So I tried to implement this plugin on both the nagios linux server and a linux client. I basically want the plugin to run on the remote machine named **machine1** in the format

```
check_uptime -w 15 -c 30
```

The plugin executes fine on both the server and the client. The plugin also exists on both of them under /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_uptime.

Here are my settings:

On the **server**:

I appended the following to **/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg**

```
# 'check_uptime' command definition for linux hosts
define command{
        command_name    check_uptime
        command_line    $USER1$/check_uptime -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
}
```

I appended the following to **/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/hosts/machine1.cfg**:

```
 define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       machine1
        service_description             Uptime
        check_command                   check_uptime
}
```

On the **machine1**:

I'm appending this to **/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg**:

```
command[check_uptime]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_uptime -w 15 -c 30
```

Then I'm testing the configuration on the server by running:

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

And I'm getting 0 warnings and 0 errors, yet in the Nagios console the service shows up as unknown.

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nver mind. I figured it out.

Looks like I have to invoke check_nrpe in **/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/hosts/machine1.cfg** as follows:

```
    define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       machine1
        service_description             Uptime
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_uptime
}
```

Edit: It also looks that the check_uptime command should not be invoked with the -H $HOSTADDRESS$ parameter in commands.cfg on the server end. Once that is removed, it will work on the server.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: For completeness: If you are using nrpe, and want to check something on a remote server that is not published over a port (i.e. number of procs, uptime, host time, load, etc) you will ALWAYS have to use "check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS -p <nrpe port> -c <check_command> -a $ARG1 $ARG2 ..." (or some variation like "check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS -p <nrpe port> -c $ARG1 -a $ARG2 ..."). <check_command> must be defined on the remote host nrpe config file.

Comment: Thanks Torian. Let me see if I understand you correctly and have all the steps down. I have already defined <check_command> on the host's nrpe.cfg file.

Comment: Do you need to define that on the server's command.cfg at all as follows? ---> # 'check_uptime' command definition for linux hosts
define command{
        command_name    check_uptime
        command_line    $USER1$/check_uptime -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 12489 -w 15 -c 30
}    I want to be able to use this to check uptime on the server as well and I can't get it to work even though it works on the client.

Comment: Basically, I'm confused about whether you define the specifics with the command itself on the server or whether that is done on the client and the server contains just a generic syntax for the command.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would put my two cents in I am using Nagios Core 4.08 and in my `commands.cfg` file I used it like this:

```
# comment: `check_uptime` this is to check system up time on linux boxes

define command {
    command_name check_uptime
    command_line $USER1$/check_uptime
    }
```

Then in the `host1.cfg` I did the following:

```
# comment: Check uptime of the server

define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       host1
    service_description             Uptime
    check_command                   check_uptime
    }
```

And the result was this:

```
Uptime
OK  06-23-2015 07:52:48 0d 0h 4m 19s    1/4 Uptime OK: 7 day(s) 23 hour(s) 5 minute(s)
```

So with just a simple addition it worked for me. Hope this helps everyone. I apologize I don't know how to format this.